# navigate into the project

Tags: helm, helm-projectile

I have lost my emacs config and I try to reconfigure my .init.el on my work station.

I have install helm and defined :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'helm-find-files)
```

I have the good windows, but in my last configuration i was able to navigate through my project with the keyboard arrow.

example :

C-x C-f --> /home/foo/bar/

left arrow --> /home/foo/

right arrow --> /home/foo/bar/

In my emacs, actually, this behaviour is not reproducted. What should I do to have it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `(customize-set-variable 'helm-ff-lynx-style-map t)` in your .emacs.

Comment: it works fine. Thank you.